# Importing shapefile into PostgreSQL failing

Tags: postgis, shapefile, postgresql

I have installed PostgreSQL 12 on my Windows 10 OS. I installed the PostGIS extension as well. I would like to import a shapefile and am
using shp2pgsql-gui to do so. The import is failing and there is no explanation why. Any ideas?

[image]

I should also add that my bigger objective is simply to load US census block shapefile data into a PostgreSQL database that is hosted by AWS RDS. I figured the easiest way to do this is to download shapefile data to a db instance on my computer and then dump this database into the RDS database. If there is an easier way, I'd accept that as well.

Comment: is there enough disk space on your RDS to host these files?

Comment: Yes it is a db.t3.large instance with 20GiB storage.

Comment: Could you try loading via QGIS instead?

Comment: FYI: the name you obscured appears in the *Log Window*. Does your user have permissions to write access the DB?